# Show time of future in pretty format using javascript

Tags: javascript, pretty-print, date-formatting

Is there a javascript which can work for future? For example i want to post an event dated on 1/11/2012, i need it to show as "one month from now" or something similar in the web page. I have gone through [pretty dates](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/) but looks like it doesn't work some times. Is there something which works for past and future time?

Comment: Yes, JS can work with *dates* regardless of if it is in the future or past as long as its after Jan 1, 1970!

Comment: You can take a datetime difference for that..

Comment: Do you want to fire a event on 1/11/2012

Comment: If it's 30 Jan, when is "one month from now"?

Comment: @techfoobar—javascript has -ve numbers too, so it can work with dates either side of the epoch.

Comment: @RobG - Thanks for the tip. That's cool to know and now i realize its a certain possibility. But will date arithmetic work correctly in that case?

Comment: Yes, though you need to be careful with date arithmetic in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function func()
{
    var mEvent = new Date('11/1/2012');
    var now = new Date();

    var timeDif = mEvent.getTime() - now.getTime();
    var dSec, dMin, dHr, dDay;

    dSec = (timeDif / 1000);
    dMin = (dSec / 60);
    dHr = (dMin / 60);
    dDay = (dHr / 24);

    var mStr = (dDay>>0) + "d, " + (dHr>>0) + "h, " + (dMin>>0) + 'm, ' + (dSec>>0) + "s.";

    if (now < mEvent)
        alert('future: ' + mStr);
    else
        alert('past: ' + mStr);
}
```